# How to use the result of mysql query as the column name of another query

Tags: php, mysql

i have a following code

```
    <?php
       include("includes\conn.php"); 
       $start = $_POST['start_date'];
       $end = $_POST['end_date'];  
       $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM data");
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
         $time_stamp = $row['time_stamp'];
         $temp_date= substr($time_stamp, 2, 12);
         $date= explode('.', $temp_date);
         $final= $date[2]. '-' .$date[1]. '-' .$date[0];
         $result1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM data WHERE $final BETWEEN $start AND $end");
         while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){
          print_r($row2);
         }
      }
  ?>
```

Error:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Nestle\trend_test.php on line 10
>      Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Nestle\trend_test.php on line 10
>      Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Nestle\trend_test.php on line 12

Your kind help is needed!

Comment: Can you give an example for a data item stored in the `time_stamp` column in the `data` table.

Comment: ""09.12.2019 12:54:50"" i have the value like this in time_stamp

Comment: Just try this and show the output: `print($time);` within the _while_ loop

Comment: ""09.12.2019 12:54:50""""09.12.2019 12:55:20""""09.12.2019 12:55:50""""09.12.2019 12:56:20""""09.12.2019 12:56:50""""09.12.2019 12:57:20""""09.12.2019 12:57:50""""09.12.2019 12:58:20""""09.12.2019 12:58:50""""09.12.2019 12:59:20""""09.12.2019 12:59:50""""09.12.2019 13:00:20""""09.12.2019 13:00:50""""09.12.2019 13:01:20""""09.12.2019 13:01:50""""09.12.2019 13:02:20""""09.12.2019 13:02:50""""09.12.2019 13:03:20""""09.12.2019 13:03:50""""09.12.2019 13:04:20""""09.12.2019 13:04:50""

Comment: To paraphrase, Your present query says 'SELECT everything WHERE 1 is BETWEEN 2 AND 3'. This is a strange request.

Comment: If it was me, I'd forget about the php stuff for now, and instead focus on the sql - starting with a date that uses a proper date data type

Comment: @Strawberry i am bound to insert this data as a string not date. Otherwise i have worked well on date data type.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Your date extraction from time_stamp might be a problem.

```
$final= substr($time_stamp, 0, 10)
```

would be better.

If needed include Quotation marks at start and end of date items within query.

Add another echo for $final before calling MySQL and you can understand better and correct yourself.

Comment: ""09.12.2019 12:54:50"" i have the value like this in time_stamp

Comment: Since your final will have dd.mm.yyyy, you need to use date_format(...) before comparing in MySQL. Add another echo for $final and you can understand better.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume that this is the data of the date in your db '09.12.2019 12:54:50' so in order to get the format yyyy-mm-dd, hence your date format has date and time, first is you remove the time:

```
$temp_date= substr('09.12.2019 12:54:50', 0, 10);
```

After getting the date, we will be making it to this format yyyy-mm-dd

```
$date= explode('.', $temp_date);
$final= $date[2]. '-' .$date[1]. '-' .$date[0];
```

As a result, $final has a value 2019-12-09 [yyyy-mm-dd] and you can now use it in the next query.

> Since your date values in db uses '.' (09.12.2019 12:54:50) instead of
>   '-' (09-12-2019 12:54:50), we made an approachable solution in it.

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Nestle\trend_test.php on line 22. I am getting this error this way when i execute the query

Comment: Please paste all your source code in order for as to manipulate a solution and prevent an error. You can edit and paste it above so that I can help you

Comment: By the way, are you aware that I edited my posted answer?

Comment: Yes i am and updated my code according to that. Kindly have a look above at my posted code.

Comment: Can you please print_r($date) after $date variable and see the result if it is yyyy-mm-dd @MariaAbdullah

Comment: print_r($date) results in Array ( [0] => 09 [1] => 12 [2] => 2019 ) and print_r($final) in this  2019-12-09

Comment: $result1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM data WHERE '".$final."' BETWEEN '".$start."' AND '".$end."'");

please try this in your result1 variable

Comment: It Worked. But it is returning the whole table data not from start and end date

Comment: Whats the purpose of your $final? Why would you like to get that? If you are using BETWEEN operator just remove $final in the query and replace it with its COLUMN_NAME

Comment: Yes that is a issue the values in the column are in this format ""09.12.2019 12:54:50"" where the values of start and end is 2019-12-09 and i want to retrieve those rows which have values between start and end

Comment: You can remove your first query and remain the second and do this.

$result1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM data WHERE time_stamp BETWEEN '".$start."' AND '".$end."'");
         while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){
          print_r($row2);
         }

@MariaAbdullah

Comment: how could it can execute when time_stamp have values like this ""09.12.2019 12:54:50"" and $start and $end have values 2019-12-09 like this

Comment: in the document, it says the COLUMN_NAME not its value :) @MariaAbdullah

Comment: SELECT * FROM data WHERE time_stamp BETWEEN '".$start."' AND '".$end."' is the solution :)